# Crystal Report Viewer Refreshing Report

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I am using C# and I am running a report in a Crystal Report viewer, now i want to refresh the report and latest data should display in crystal report viewer, database is Sybase database.

1) I am having 2 crystal reports, each report having different stored procedures.

2) In dropdown i kept 2 report names, now the requirement is based on the selected report the respective stored procedure should call and once clicked on "Refresh" button manually created,the latest report should get from sybase database and display the latest data in Crystal Report Viewer.

so please send me the full code for this.

Regards,
Ramachandran.

Comment: In order to make suggestions, show us your Refresh button click handler, please.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [thread](https://scn.sap.com/thread/3178809).

Basically, I don't think free Crystal Report Viewer will allow to refresh report  (i.e. to connect to different datasource).

Your options are:

1) Consider one of the 3rd-party viewers listed at [Crystal Reports viewer comparison](http://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#viewers)

2) Create a simple viewer of your own using the .NET or Java SDK

Comment: My requirement is, i want the latest report to be fetch from database and display in Crystal Report Viewer. so for this how i want to proceed. can you give me the steps and source code.